# How can I set path of vim from the shell command result

Tags: vim

I'd like to set c++ header file path automatically from .vimrc.
So I tried to write .vimrc file as shown below:

```
let g:gcpp_headers_path=system("g++ --version | grep g++ | awk '{print \"/usr/include/c++/\"$NF}'")

"if isdirectory(gcpp_headers_path)
  set path+=g:gcpp_headers_path
"endif
```

from the vimrc above I found the vim variable path set as shown below:

```
:set path?
path=.,/usr/include,,,g:gcpp_headers_path
```

The wanted output is as shown below:

```
:set path?
path=.,/usr/include,/usr/include/c++/7.5.0
```

I'd like to get this reviewed. Could someone advise me?

F.Y.I. The command in system() is shown below:

```
~$ g++ --version | grep g++ | awk '{print "/usr/include/c++/"$NF}'
/usr/include/c++/7.5.0
```

For documentation I am writing my answer found here:

```
let g:gcpp_headers_path = system("g++ --version | grep g++ | awk '{print \"/usr/include/c++/\"$NF}'")

execute 'set path+=' . g:gcpp_headers_path
```

My vim version is Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jan 20 2022 02:47:53)

[I raised new post for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71276889/how-can-i-set-path-of-vim-from-the-shell-command-result-for-windows)

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:set` doesn't evaluate expressions so you can't use variables directly. You have two solutions.

1. Use `:help :let` instead, which can evaluate expressions:

   ```
   :let &path .= ',' . g:gcpp_headers_path
   ```

   Notes:

   - the `&` before the option name,
   - the different operator, because we are concatenating the original value, a string, with another string,
   - the `,`, needed to separate your custom path from what's already there,
   - the `.` concatenation operator.
2. Use `:help :execute` to build the proper `:set` command before executing it:

   ```
   :execute 'set path+=' . g:gcpp_headers_path
   ```

Comment: Thank you! The second one works! execute 'set path+=' . g:gcpp_headers_path Note the concatenate operator was a single dot(.) not double.

Comment: You may have an older Vim, then.

Comment: My vim version is Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jan 20 2022 02:47:53)

Comment: Older Vim indeed. Current version is 8.2 and 9 is around the corner. I'll edit the answer for better portability.